# Parse human-format date ranges in Python

Tags: python, parsing, datetime, date

I have some human-style date ranges, in strings, like the following:

```
22-24th April 2012
14-23 July
20th June - 5th July
```

I want to parse these in Python so that I can end up with two datetime objects: one for the start, one for the end.

Is there any module that will let me do this? I've tried `parsedatetime`, and it looks like the `evalRange` function within that may do it (see http://code-bear.com/code/parsedatetime/docs/index.html for documentation), but it doesn't seem to parse anything at all, and just returns the current date/time, twice.

Any ideas?

Comment: robin,

imho - with the variety of these strings regex's and custom logic are your best bet. -dc

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up writing a Python module to do this, which I have now open-sourced. It is available for download on [Github](https://github.com/robintw/daterangeparser), there is [documentation](http://daterangeparser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), and it can be installed from PyPI using:

```
pip install daterangeparser
```

For those who are interested, the module works by creating a full parser using [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/), a great (and remarkably easy-to-use) tool.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dateutil.parser`. But it does not handle date ranges. You may need to apply a regular expression before.

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse("20th June")
```

returns `datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 20, 0, 0)`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Based on previous answers, what you could do is:

1. Preprocess your input so that you get the beginning and end date (for instance: `20th June` and `5th July`). In your first example (`date_range == 22-24th July 2012`) you can do that by using `date_range.split(' ')[0].split('-')`: this will return `['22', '24th']` (just drop the `th` and similar)
2. Get `datetime` objects from those dates using `dateutil.parser` : `dateutil.parser.parse('22 July 2012')`

Here's an implementation of what was previously said:

```
import dateutil.parser
date_range = '20-22th July 2013'
date_range = date_range.lower()
for suffix in {'th', 'rd', 'st'}:
    date_range.replace(suffix, '')
days = date_range.split(' ')[0].split('-')
month_year = date_range.split(' ')[1]
begin, end = days[0] + ' ' + month_year, days[1] + ' ' + month_year
begin_date = dateutil.parser.parse(begin)
end_date = dateutil.parser.parse(end)
```